# ipython uses wrong python version with anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

After activating my anaconda Python 3.6 environment with

```
source activate py36
```

if I type

```
python
```

I go into python 3.6, as expected. But if I type

```
ipython
```

I go into an ipython environment based python 3.5.5, which is the same python version I get using

```
source activate base
```

and then

```
python
```

How can I get into an ipython environment using my anaconda-supplied python 3.6 interpreter? I have updated my anaconda environment with

```
conda update anaconda
```

and

```
conda update conda
```

Doing so does not help.

EDIT:

I hadn't realized that I had to install ipython separately for the python 3.6 environment; I'd thought it was a default part of anaconda. So

```
conda install ipython
```

after

```
source activate py36
```

did the trick. It doesn't seem optimal that after activating a particular environment, `ipython` may bring up a completely different anaconda-based environment. I'd prefer it to simply cause a "command not found" error. Bringing up the wrong environment without making it very obvious that that is happening could lead to confusion or problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hadn't realized that I had to install ipython separately for the python 3.6 environment; I'd thought it was a default part of anaconda. So

```
conda install ipython
```

after

```
source activate py36
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done `hash -r` since entering the conda environment? Bash can cache paths to executables, so sometimes it doesn't use the one reported by which. Running `hash -r` resets the cache

Maybe you need also to update `ipython` `conda update ipython`

Comment: hash -r doesn't help, and when I do conda update ipython, it says "All requested packages already installed". I don't know if it's relevant, but I can't run conda update if I've activated my python 3.6 environment; I have to do "source activate base" before I can successfully run it. Otherwise I get the error "PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix."