# Python version changes when I open IPython

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am using a Conda environment with Python version 3.11, but when I open IPython from the terminal it opens in version 3.8. What should I do to open it in the correct version of my Conda environment (3.11)?

```
cd ~
python --version
```

Output:

> Python 3.11.4

```
ipython
```

Output:

> ```
> Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35)
> Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
> IPython 7.28.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
> ```

Comment: You should `conda install ipython` after `conda activate py311`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ipython uses wrong python version with anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707728/ipython-uses-wrong-python-version-with-anaconda)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that IPython opens in the correct version of your conda environment (3.11), you can follow these steps:

First, activate your conda environment with Python 3.11. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

**conda activate your_env_name**

Replace your_env_name with the name of your conda environment.

Once the environment is activated, you need to install IPython within this environment. This ensures that IPython is associated with the correct Python version. Run the following command:

**conda install ipython**

This will install IPython in your conda environment.

After the installation is complete, you can now launch IPython from the terminal, and it should open with the correct Python version (3.11) associated with your conda environment.

**ipython**

This should open IPython with the correct Python version from your conda environment.

To ensure that IPython is launched with the correct version of Python corresponding to your conda environment, you can follow these steps:

Make sure your conda environment is activated before launching IPython. You can activate it by running:

**conda activate py311**

After activating the environment, simply type ipython in the terminal. This should launch IPython with the version of Python associated with your activated conda environment (in this case, Python 3.11).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: That's actually what I did. As you can see I have my 3.11 environment activated (py311) before I open ipython.